# Replacements in proofs

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

A formal proof in propositional logic is considered a sequence of formulas such that every formula is either an axiom, a member of the presupposed set, or derived by previous ones through a rule of inference. If a formal system proves an equivalence $\phi\leftrightarrow\psi$, I.e. $\vdash\phi\leftrightarrow\psi$, can all occurrences of $\phi$ may be replaced in the proof by $\psi$ and vice versa?

If one haves a translation $t$ one logic $\vdash_1$ into another $\vdash_2$ s.t. the one proves $\vdash_2\phi\leftrightarrow t(\phi)$, does this then infer that $\Gamma\vdash_2\phi$ if and only if $t(\Gamma)\vdash_1t(\phi)$ by a translation of the elements of the proof.

Comment: What makes these logics different (or alternatively, the same)? What properties is $t$ supposed to preserve? A logic need not have anything like $\leftrightarrow$. It's not clear why $\phi$ would be in both the domain and codomain of $t$.

Comment: Ah ok sorry, well I suppose that the second is a language extension if the first one s.t they have the classical operators. @DerekElkins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second paragraph (even with your comment) is unclear, and, with your comment, seems require introducing a bunch of machinery and noise that has no bearing on the content of your question.

As for your first question, in classical propositional logic you can define a relation on formulas via $\varphi\sim\psi$ if and only if $\vdash\varphi\leftrightarrow\psi$. This relation is a congruence on formulas with respect to the logical connectives. That is, it's an equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetric, and transitive) and, if we define all other connectives in terms of $\neg$ and $\land$, that if $\varphi\sim\varphi'$ and $\psi\sim\psi'$ then $\neg\varphi\sim\neg\varphi'$ and $\varphi\land\psi\sim\varphi'\land\psi'$. Prove all of this.

You can then easily prove from modus ponens (do this), that if $\varphi\sim\psi$ then $\vdash\varphi$ if and only if  $\vdash\psi$. Because $\sim$ is a congruence this means that for any formula containing $\varphi$, call it $F(\varphi)$, if $\varphi\sim\psi$ then $F(\varphi)\sim F(\psi)$, thus $\vdash F(\varphi)$ if and only if $\vdash F(\psi)$. You can use the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) to extend this to conditional provability.

As an addendum, if we quotient the set of formulas by $\sim$ we get the [Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra) which for classical propositional logic will be a Boolean algebra.

Comment: My question is, more explicitly, if you consider a proof for a formula $\phi$ as a chain of formulas, i.e. $\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_n,\phi$, and replace all occurrences of a formula $\psi$ with a corresponding provably-equivalent formula, is the resulting chain still proving $\phi$? @Derek Elkins

Comment: Choose $\psi$ to be $\phi$. Then you'll be proving something provably equivalent to $\phi$, not (necessarily) $\phi$ itself. Let's say you use modus ponens as $\cfrac{\vdash\chi\quad\vdash\chi\to\phi}{\phi}$. Choose $\psi=\chi\to\phi$ and replace it with $\top\land(\chi\to\psi)$ which is provably equivalent. Now modus ponens no longer applies. To make use of a non-trivial equivalence, you do need to modify the derivation, albeit in a relatively systematic way.